# Connection between Bond dimension and Physical Lattice Sites for Tensor Networks

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-information

Does the bond dimension for a tensor network (say MERA, for argument's sake) bear any physical consequences for the lattice structure that it is approximating?

More succintly: what dictates bond dimension for a tensor network? does it have any relationship to the physical sites on the lattice?

Answer (score 2):

The bond dimension is related to the amount of entanglement in the system. If your bond dimension is larger, you can capture the physics of systems with a larger amount of entanglement, or you can capture the physics of systems with a given amount of entanglement more accurately.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you for the response. So as I understand you, there is only a relationship between accuracy of parameterization for the lattice, and the bond dimension, which is the tool used to tweak this. Does this have any physical significance for the lattice if we change to a scale-invariant network?

Comment: @MatthewSteinberg13 I'm afraid I don't understand the question.